# How to properly calling a signal when using epoll_pwait()?

Tags: c++, epoll

I happen to have a main loop that processes multiple things. For instance, I have 'timers' that are meant to be run every 1 second, I also have an epoll_pwait() function with a blocking (-1) timeout.

How am I supposed to use sigprocmask if I want to continue running these timers, given that my epoll_pwait will be blocking?

am I supposed to use a thread that calls a signal so I can continue looping? if so, is sigprocmask even thread safe?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of timers are you using? Perhaps you might consider using [`timerfd_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) to create timers using descriptors which can be polled with epoll?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I basically have a class Timer that can be virtualized in C++ with specific commands inside of a Run() funcion. A timer manager class checks whether there are pending timers or not during each loop.

Comment: You may not call `sigprocmask` before `epoll_pwait` ?

Comment: I mean, what is the kind of Linux timer you use? Could those be changed to use the descriptor-timers?

Comment: I have researched more about this issue. I think you've provided a great solution using timerfd. This will wake epoll_wait, thus allowing mainloop to continue. Thank you very much!